# Using jQuery Ajax callbacks in wordpress theme

Tags: ajax, wordpress, jquery

I am developing custom theme for WP and I have a problem with ajax callbacks...
This is my header:

```
<script>    
//alert("Data Loaded");
    $('#domaincheck').submit(function(){
        alert("Button pressed");
        $.post('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/check.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });             
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

In my theme file i have simple form like:

```
<form id="domaincheck">
Name: <input type="text" name="urname">
Birthplace: <input type="text" name="urbirth">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now when I click submit button - pages just reloads :(  when I move this out of WordPress everything is working properly. Is there a way to make this to work in WordPress ?  Also another strange thing is when I wrap JS code in "document ready" - javascript is not working at all.... without documentready it displays the Alert - but not the callback - it just reloads page... Once again - outside of wordpress template it works like it should.

Thanks, Peter

Comment: I'm assuming that #domaincheck is actually submitting. try change function() to function(ev), then before the alert("Button pressed");, put a ev.preventDefault();

Comment: Thanks for reply, but that didn't help.

Comment: Doing ajax in wordpress is a little "different", and you should probably use the built in functions, like the already defined "ajaxurl" etc. Here's a [**LINK**](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) to how it's normally done in plugins, widgets etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done on my Localhost and this is doing a ajax call very fine:

i `added one main jquery plugin` reference in `header.php` file at `<head>`

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(function(){
       $('#domaincheck').submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           alert("Button pressed");
           $.post('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/check.php',$(this).serialize(), function(data){
               alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
           });
       });
   });
</script>
```

and this one is the `check.php` file php code:

```
<?php
    if((isset($_POST['urname'])) && (isset($_POST['urbirth']))){
        echo $_POST['urname'];
        echo $_POST['urbirth'];
    }
?>
```

and i got the alert of the posted data.

try this and see if this helps.

Comment: That did work, but I have a question tho... WP is already loading jQuery by default. Now when I remove call to jquery (from the top of this script), jquery loads by WP default and function isn't working. When I restore that line which calls google hosted jQuery - script is working again, but I have 2 jQuery loading (WP default and this google hosted). Is that something I should be concerned about ?

Comment: actually i saw the source of the wordpress and i did not find any jquery plugin used by the current theme. so if your theme is having the jquery then there should be no issues. otherwise you have to put that link.

Comment: Now what I did is I changed default WP jquery in my functions.php like this: if( !is_admin()){
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"), false, '1.8.3');
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
...and it loads this version, but none the less when I remove second call (from your script) script isn't working, although it loads same jQuery.... I just guess I NEED 2 instances in order for this to work... dunno why...

Comment: Do you have link of the jquery in your page source. with the this code. you changed.

Comment: another thing is that **you have to have jquery in your theme's js folder**.

Comment: Yes, actually after install WP was loading this:
...some scripts...
<script type='text/javascript' src='MY-WP-URL-HERE/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>
...some scripts...
after functions modification I checked and it did load: src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js?ver=1.8.3  ON EXACT SAME SPOT in header... but when I remove a second call from script you provided - script isn't working... actually no matter what version of jQuery I choose script doesn't work until it has that second call. Everything is working, not sure why it needs second call

Comment: Anyway - I am happy - it works and it seems that there is n no conflict what-so-ever even when 2 jQuerys are called... THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR HELP BTW !

Comment: **<script type='text/javascript' src='MY-WP-URL-HERE/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>** this seems to have in includes folder not in your theme's js folder.

Comment: that should be like this one **src='your project url/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/js/jquery.js'**